# Silverstripe 3 - add css class to CMS form field

Tags: silverstripe

How can I go about add a css class to the CheckboxSetField below - I've tried the setAttribute method but it has no effect (using SS 3.0):

```
$checkboxFieldSet = new CheckboxSetField('CampusPage', 'Campuses (select multiple)*', $campusArea->map());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$checkboxFieldSet->addExtraClass("my-class");`

API Docs: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FormField.html#_addExtraClass